# What are the actual names of the stages in Centipede?

Tags: centipede

In the 1998 PC version of Centipede there are  many stages of 5 levels each. The bosses I was told helped contribute the name. These are:

1. Giant Ant
2. Giant Praying Mantis
3. Huge Wasp
4. (there are two more but I can't remember what they are)

What are the five worlds called?

Comment: May I suggest that you do a bit of basic research before asking your questions? a simple google search should yield plenty of information.

Comment: Eh, if he asks it here, other people who Google it may end up here.   That's a bonus as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Oh, we'll have the questions; they're allowed.  Doesn't mean we can't downvote it for little to no effort shown prior to asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centipede_%281998_video_game%29) they are:
Weedom, Frostonia, Inferium, Enigma, and Evile